# Simple client / server TCP c++

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, server, client

I have always been able to find a way to fix my code just debugging and browsing the web but I am stuck on some code right now and I don't see what kind of tests I could do to debug it.

Basically I'm trying to implement a simple Client/Server relation in C++, I commented every line to be sure I was understanding what I'm doing but still, it doesn't work.

Here's my Client code :

```
void startClient(){ 
int wsaStatus, connectStatus; //check errors
WSADATA WSAData;
wsaStatus=WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WSAData);
if (wsaStatus != NO_ERROR) {
    std::cout << "WSA Startup failed with error : " << wsaStatus;
}
SOCKET sock; //defines the sockets TO SEND
SOCKADDR_IN sin;//information about the socket

sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");//ip of the server you want to connect to
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;//family of the socket, for internet it's AF_INET
sin.sin_port = htons(1234);// 23 for telnet etc, it's the port
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);//second parameter is the type of the socket, SOCK_STREAM opens a connection ( use for TCD ), SOCK_DGRAM doesn't connect() or accept() it's used for UDP
if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    std::cout << "INVALID SOCKET " << WSAGetLastError();
    WSACleanup();
}

bind(sock, (SOCKADDR *)&sin, sizeof(sin)); //binds the socket to the port and the adress above

char buffer[255]; //creates a buffer to receive messages

connectStatus=connect(sock, (SOCKADDR *)&sin, sizeof(sin)); //function to connect to the server
if (connectStatus == SOCKET_ERROR) { //it returns 0 if no error occurs
    std::cout << "Connection failed with error : " << WSAGetLastError();
    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();
}

int iResult = send(sock, "Hello world!\r\n", 14, 0);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    std::cout << "Send failed with error : " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
}

closesocket(sock);
WSACleanup();

system("pause");
```

Here's my Server code :

```
void startServer(){

int wsaStatus; //check errors
WSADATA WSAData;
wsaStatus=WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WSAData);
if (wsaStatus != NO_ERROR) {
    std::cout << "WSA Startup failed with error : " << wsaStatus;
}


SOCKET sock; //defines the sockets
SOCKADDR_IN sin; //information about the socket

sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); //since it's the server we accept any connection
sin.sin_family = AF_INET; //family of the socket, for internet it's AF_INET
sin.sin_port = htons(1234); // 23 for telnet etc, it's the port
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); //second parameter is the type of the socket, SOCK_STREAM opens a connection ( use for TCD ), SOCK_DGRAM doesn't connect() or accept() it's used for UDP
if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    std::cout << "INVALID SOCKET " << WSAGetLastError();
    WSACleanup();
}

bind(sock, (SOCKADDR *)&sin, sizeof(sin)); //binds the socket to the port and the adress above
char buffer[255]; //to receive the messages

listen(sock, 1); //listens on the port of the socket, second parameter is the maximum of connections accepted
while (1)
{

    int sizeof_sin = sizeof(sin); //size of the socket used to take the information from the client connected
    sock = accept(sock, (SOCKADDR *)&sin, &sizeof_sin); //first parameter : socket, second parameter : client information socket, third parameter : size of the information about the socket
    std::cout << "Connection ok" << std::endl;
    if (sock != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        closesocket(sock);
        std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
    }
}


WSACleanup();
```

So I start the Server first and it stops at the accept() function waiting for a connection, then I start the Client which is sending the message successfully BUT the Server still waits at the accept() function and is not getting any message.

As you can see I implemented lots of errors checking, still not helping :')

Cheers !

Comment: check for bind(sock, (SOCKADDR *)&sin, sizeof(sin)); return value.Whether it is successful or not.

Comment: If on linux, you could print strerror(errno)  to get the error notified by OS, but I have no idea of how it's done in windows

Comment: In your server code, you are reusing the same socket you listen with to store the result of accept.  Accept creates a brand-new socket, so use a new socket variable.

Comment: Also, in the client, you don't need to call bind.  The socket will be bound implicitly on connect - Right now you're trying to bind the client and server to the same port.  That's not going to work out well.

Comment: First, thank you all guys for your answers it really helped me understand. I think the problem here was my poor understanding of how sockets acutally work ! -I'm going to edit my code as soon as it works properly (now the Client / Server communication works but I still have some bugs I can fix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to bind the client and server to the same port, and you're not checking the return value of bind in either case for an error.  Bind is something that will fail regularly because another program could be using the port you want, so its a return value you should always check.

In general, the client does not need to bind unless you really want it to have a specific local port, and in most situations, you don't care what port it's using.  The server must bind because you really need to know the port in order to connect.  You don't need to know (normally) the client port for anything.

Also, in the server, should shouldn't reuse the `sock` variable when you call accept.  Make a new socket variable for the return value of accept.  Right now, your program is leaking resources because your listen socket remains open, but you have no way to access it because you overwrite the sock variable.

Since you're using Windows, a great tool for helping with socket programs is [TCPView from SysInternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897437.aspx).  It lists all open sockets on the system and their current status and bytes transfered.

Comment: I made it work thanks to your help, last thing I don't understand is you said "you don't care what the client port is using" but if I change the port to another port that is different from the server port then it doesn't work.     Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Change it where?  In your call to connect it has to be the same as the server because that's the only way it knows how to connect.  A connected socket has a local port and a remote port.  What you pass to connect will be the "remote" port, and what you bind with will be local.  If you don't bind, a local port is chosen at random.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you calling a *bind* in the client code? this is not necessary. Bind should be called by server only. TCP client will use a random port to communicate with the Server so there's not need to bind on the client side. Additionally, a bind on the same port from two different processes will fail since the port is already in use. So, remove the bind and re-test your code.

In order to test things separately, you can use the **netcat** tool. It's a very simple tool that can acts a server or client:

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat

So to test the client just launch the netcat in server mode as the following:

```
nc -l your_ip port
```

And launch your client, so you should see that the client is connecting correctly to the already launched server. Similarly, you can test your server by launching nc in client mode.

Additionally, once you launch the server you can use the **netstat** (as root) tool to make sure that the server is running on the correct IP/port. So, a command like the following could be useful to see in which state is your server's TCP socket (listening, etc). Take a look to the manual page of netstat it's another very useful tool.

```
netstat -anp | grep your_port
```

Using netstat you could also see what port is being used by the client once it's connected to your server and the status of the TCP connection.